# Oracle how to find the blocking sql

Tags: oracle, locks

I have got a java app which after x number of requests just hangs. Looking at the app, it hangs on the execution of a query against an oracle database. Checked the blocking session [using this sql](https://pastebin.com/5VkQreHU) and getting this:

[image: blocking_sessions]

Clearly SID 68 is blocking the SID 10. But why isn't it showing the blocking sql? The output from `v$lock` shows the following locks:

[image: output from v$lock]

How do I find the actual blocking sqls?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not showing the blocking SQL *statement* is because this cannot be known.

Consider this scenario:
Session 1 - 'SELECT FOR UPDATE ... WHERE EMP_ID = '123" (thus locking that row)
SESSION 1 -  .... some other SQL (still hasn't committed)
Session 1 -  .... some other SQL (still hasn't committed)
Session 1 -  .... some other SQL (still hasn't committed)
Session 1 -  .... some other SQL (still hasn't committed)

Session 2 - 'SELECT FOR UPDATE ... WHERE EMP_ID = '123" (is blocked by session 1, which _still has not committed and so is still holding it's lock)

So, we can know that session 1 is the blocking session, but there is no view that will indicate that it was the sql 3 previous to it's current sql that actuall placed the lock.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the blocking session is inactive, you must look at PREV_SQL_ID on V$SESSION in order to identify the last sql executed by the session that remains inactive.

V$LOCK lists the locks currently held by the Oracle Database and outstanding requests for a lock or latch. There are many types of locks in Oracle that is why you have so many rows on that view.

Regards

Comment: thanks, the prev_sql is a select query, how can it block?

Comment: do you mean how can you unlock ??

Comment: to unlock the active session you need to kill the inactive session by ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'SID,SERIAL#' IMMEDIATE

Comment: Any previous execution in open transaction can block it. Oracle doesn't store blocking sql, just blocked resource and blocker

Comment: Don't kill, just ask blocker to commit or rollback his transaction

Comment: Kill will be the only option if the pending commit/rollback is out of the control of the client process. If the client process which is in the transaction inactive has yet control you can rollback or commit to release the lock